# How to reduce rows in Altair plots using groupby in pandas

Tags: pandas, altair

Okay, I have a dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

    #"https://www.who.int/data/gho/data/indicators/indicator-details/GHO/mean-bmi-(kg-m-)-(crude-estimate)")

df = pd.read_csv("obesity_WHO.csv")
df_cropped = df.loc[:, ["Location", "Period", "FactValueNumericHigh"]]
```

Tried to reduce size:

```
df_cropped.groupby(["Location", "Period"]).mean().shape
```

result is:

(8190, 1)

What magic do I need so I can beneath the 5,000 rows limit to visualise:

```
alt.Chart(df_cropped).mark_point(filled=True).encode(
    alt.X("Period"),
    alt.Y("FactValueNumericHigh")
)
```

Comment: `alt.data_transformers.disable_max_rows()` Please refer to [https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/large_datasets.html](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/large_datasets.html)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments:

`alt.data_transformers.disable_max_rows()` or any of the other options listed in https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/large_datasets.html